# Worrying about WAI-ARIA support

Tags: html, browser, operating-system, accessibility, wai-aria

Do i need to worry about WAI-ARIA support? I mean, HTML is not so strict as programming languages are, so the attributes will not throw errors. Besides, WAI-ARIA attributes enhance the accessibility of the page and if the specific feature is supported, the accessibility is improved, if not, it will be ignored.

So, for me, i don't need to worry about WAI-ARIA support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML validator will not usually complain about screwy WAI-ARIA attributes, but there **is** a formal spec for which attributes are allowed, and where. You can't just sprinkle ARIA arbitrarily throughout the DOM and assume that no harm will come of it.

Misuse of ARIA can make your web content completely unusable by those who rely on assistive technology. (For example, putting `aria-hidden="true"` on the body will hide absolutely everything but the page title from screen readers). In the worst cases, screwy markup like this can (and has) lead to litigation.

The first rule of ARIA is **"don't use ARIA if the same result can be achieved using the host language"** (i.e. if you can achieve the same result with plain HTML, do so).

Having said that, there are certain kinds of user interface that require ARIA for proper WCAG conformance, and if you find yourself using any ARIA at all, you should use it properly and according to the spec. The more exotic your UI, the more likely it is that ARIA will be necessary to make it accessible. For example, HTML has no semantic for "toolbar", "tablist" or "menuitemcheckbox", and has no way to express the state of a toggle button to assistive technology. You are obliged to use ARIA in such cases, if you want your page to be accessible.

Browser development tools such as aXe and WAVE will tell you if you have "mechanically" misused ARIA (i.e. deviating from the ARIA spec), for example if you put an `aria-label` on an element that cannot be named.

In other words, you should not regard the quality of your ARIA coding as a "non-problem".

So yes, worry about it to the extent that you use it. If you don't use any ARIA, you don't need to worry about it at all.

Comment: Rule of thumb: It's better to not use ARIA Attributes than wrong attributes. Depending on which website you're programming for. It might be necessary to make it accessible to the full extent by law. In Europe, for example, EN 301 549 requires governmental websites or public services such as hospitals, transportation companies etc to be accessible.

Comment: But I mean the support across browsers, screen readers and operating systems. I don't mean using WAI-ARIA attributes as much as I can. I mean, if i need to use an aria feature, and I don't know if it is not supported somewhere, should I look up its compatibility, which might not have a conclusive resource about, and know it?